# Is there research on leveraging quantum computing in the theory component of classical SMT solvers?

Tags: classical-computing, research

Satisfiability Modulo Theories (SMT) extends the concept of boolean satisfiability (SAT) by including theories such as arithmetic, arrays, bit vectors, and functions. In a typical SMT problem, a decision procedure based on a SAT solver handles the boolean structure of the formula, while a theory solver tackles the constraints specific to the given theory. In case of conflicts, the theory solver generates new conflict clauses which the decision procedure can use to refine its search.

There is a significant amount of research on employing quantum algorithms to enhance the performance of SAT solvers. However, I'm intrigued by the idea of utilizing quantum computing in the theory component of classical SMT solvers.

Has there been any exploration in this direction? Is it conceptually feasible to utilize quantum computing as a theory in an otherwise classical SMT? If so, could such a solver be advantageous for a certain class of problems? Any insights or references to relevant research would be greatly appreciated.